# Function is recalled before end of animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, callback

```
function seite(j, element, callback){
            if (j==0) {$(element).css({"visibility": "hidden"});};
            var ele = $(element).eq(j), str = ele.text(), progress = 0;
            ele.text('');
            $(element).eq(j).css({"visibility": "visible"});
            var timer = setInterval(function() {
                ele.text(str.substring(0, ++progress));
                if (progress >= str.length){
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    if (j==$(element).length) {
                        callback();
                    };
                    $('body').animate({
                        scrollTop: ($(element).eq(j).offset().top)
                    },500);
                    seite(j+1, element, callback);
                }
            }, 10);
        }
```

This works like a typewriter for elements of the same class. The problem ist that `seite()` is called before the end of the animation, so that the animation never stops and lags.

Comment: Use the animate method complete callback: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: `animate` is not blocking. You need to use it's callback if you want something to happen only *after* the animation is done.

Comment: But when I put `seite(j+1, element, callback);` inside the animation callback, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: @user3503803: Please show how you attempted to "put `seite(j+1, element, callback);` inside the animation callback". That was the correct technique, but you may have made a mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem (shown in your own answer) is not deferring the callback (it still runs immediately).

You need to wrap the calls, to your callback, in anonymous functions.

Try this:

```
$('body').animate({
    scrollTop: ($(element).eq(j).offset().top),
    done: function(){ seite(j+1, element, callback); }
},500);
```

or

```
$('body').animate({
    scrollTop: ($(element).eq(j).offset().top)
},500, function(){ seite(j+1, element, callback); });
```

Comment: @user3503803: please provide a JSFiddle, so *any other issues* can also be resloved :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution (simple syntax error):

```
function seite(i, element, callback) {
window.j = i;
if (window.j == 0) {
    $(element).css({
        "visibility": "hidden"
    });
};
var ele = $(element).eq(window.j),
    str = ele.text(),
    progress = 0;
ele.text('');
$(element).eq(window.j).css({
    "visibility": "visible"
});
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    ele.text(str.substring(0, ++progress));
    if (progress >= str.length) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        if (window.j == $(element).length) {
            callback();
        } else {
            $('body').animate({
                scrollTop: ($(element).eq(window.j).offset().top),
            }, {
                duration: 500,
                complete: function () {
                    seite(window.j + 1, element, callback);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}, 10);
```

}